# how to insert an image into a database using php

Tags: php, mysql, image

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Inserting images into a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236652/inserting-images-into-a-database)
>   [Store images in database or on file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550197/store-images-in-database-or-on-file-system)

Hi,

I want to insert product image to database using php. please help me out.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

1. Insert Binary data for the image.
2. Insert location of image into
   database and keep image file at a
   place accessible by your
   application.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you really want to store images in the database? Its faster to upload the image to the file system and store its location in the database, faster in both upload and accessing.

If however it is storing images as binary in the DB for security for example:

[**Google Has Many Answers**](http://tinyurl.com/4pfo7sl)

Like:

[**Tutorial Storing Images MySQL PHP**](http://forum.codecall.net/php-tutorials/6937-tutorial-storing-images-mysql-php.html)

Comment: +9000 Love me some bookmarklets... :)

Comment: SO is a place to ask programming questions and get answers. "Google" is not an answer. Please don't turn this into yet another site where people are afraid to ask questions.